# null reference exception while getting form value in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, nullreferenceexception

This is my code:

```
public ActionResult Register(FormCollection form)
{
    RegisterViewModel registerViewModel = new RegisterViewModel();
    registerViewModel.CaptchaInCache = new CacheWrapper().Get(form["GuidForCaptch"]).ToString();

    // some code here

}
```

I am getting null reference exception in the below line:

```
registerViewModel.CaptchaInCache =
    new CacheWrapper().Get(form["GuidForCaptch"]).ToString();
```

Can any one help me to resolve this. What am i doing wrong here.

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to add 'a' to GuidForCaptch?

Comment: What you do in the view? there is input named "GuidForCaptch"? (maybe a typo with GuidForCaptcha)

Comment: Even i make it "GuidForCaptcha" its still same error and that's just a string that i am using.

Comment: OK, but post what you do in the view. as stated in another answer maybe Form["GuidForCaptch"] is null (so post the html) or your CacheWrapper().Get() return null. which one is null?

Comment: @Iridio CacheWrapper().Get() return null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it might be too specific to your application to know exactly what to do.  However, this should tell you exactly where the problem is:

```
var guidForCaptch = form["GuidForCaptch"];

if (guidForCaptch == null)
{
    throw new ArgumentNullException("GuidForCaptch is null");
}

var cacheWrapper = new CacheWrapper().Get(guidForCaptch);

if (cacheWrapper == null)
{
    throw new ArgumentNullException("CacheWrapper is null");
}
```